# Application Name, package name and app icon from RunningTaskInfo In Android

Tags: android, package-managers

I have list of running task by the following code .

```
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Now I want to get app name, package name and app icon of these running tasks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  public void trythis(Context m_context )
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> m_runningProcesses = getRunningProcess(m_context);
     PackageManager pm = m_context.getPackageManager();
    if (m_runningProcesses.size() > 0)
            {
     Iterator<RunningAppProcessInfo> it = m_runningProcesses.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext())
                {
                    boolean isInternetPermission = false;
                    RunningAppProcessInfo rapInfo = (RunningAppProcessInfo) it
                            .next();

PackageInfo pkgInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(rapInfo.pkgList[0],
                            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

                    ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(
                                pkgInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, 0);
                    //For icon
                        Drawable iconp;
                        iconp = appInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

    //Application name:

     String Appname = appInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                                .toString();

    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the variable  'pkgInfo' ?

Comment: The method getRunningProcess(Context) is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: you can get by getApplicationContext in Activity

Comment: @osimerpothe when you use this function,pass the context to function.For getting the correct context use getApplicationContext android API.